# Using JSONDecoder in Apollo GraphQl client in swift language

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo

I used JSONDecoder to convert data into Model in graphql. I could not figure out why the decode in the code below is nil when i print?. Since I am new to graphql, I couldn't figure out whether using JSONDecoder is good. I also wanted to know if there is another alternative to use JSONDecoder in graphql?

```
apollo.fetch(query: LaunchListQuery()) {[weak self] result in
      switch result {
      case .success(let result):
        do {

          let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: result.data!.jsonObject, options: .allowFragments)
          let decode:LaunchesModal = try JSONDecoder().decode(LaunchesModal.self, from: data)
          print(decode)
        }catch (let error) {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
      case .failure(let error):
        print("Failure! Error: \(error)")
      }
    }
```

LaunchesModel i created

```
struct LaunchesModal: Codable {
  var typeName:String?
  var cursor:String?
  var hasmore:Bool?
  enum CodingKeys: String,CodingKey {
    case cursor = "cursor"
    case hasmore = "hasmore"
    case typeName = "__typename"
  }
}
```

Graphql query

```
query LaunchList {
 launches {
  cursor
  hasMore
 }
}
```

API.swift file created by Apollo client

```
// This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.
import Apollo
import Foundation
public final class LaunchListQuery: GraphQLQuery {
 /// The raw GraphQL definition of this operation.
 public let operationDefinition =
  """
  query LaunchList {
   launches {
    __typename
    cursor
    hasMore
   }
  }
  """
 public let operationName = "LaunchList"
 public init() {
 }
 public struct Data: GraphQLSelectionSet {
  public static let possibleTypes = ["Query"]
  public static let selections: [GraphQLSelection] = [
   GraphQLField("launches", type: .nonNull(.object(Launch.selections))),
  ]
  public private(set) var resultMap: ResultMap
  public init(unsafeResultMap: ResultMap) {
   self.resultMap = unsafeResultMap
  }
  public init(launches: Launch) {
   self.init(unsafeResultMap: ["__typename": "Query", "launches": launches.resultMap])
  }
  public var launches: Launch {
   get {
    return Launch(unsafeResultMap: resultMap["launches"]! as! ResultMap)
   }
   set {
    resultMap.updateValue(newValue.resultMap, forKey: "launches")
   }
  }
  public struct Launch: GraphQLSelectionSet {
   public static let possibleTypes = ["LaunchConnection"]
   public static let selections: [GraphQLSelection] = [
    GraphQLField("__typename", type: .nonNull(.scalar(String.self))),
    GraphQLField("cursor", type: .nonNull(.scalar(String.self))),
    GraphQLField("hasMore", type: .nonNull(.scalar(Bool.self))),
   ]
   public private(set) var resultMap: ResultMap
   public init(unsafeResultMap: ResultMap) {
    self.resultMap = unsafeResultMap
   }
   public init(cursor: String, hasMore: Bool) {
    self.init(unsafeResultMap: ["__typename": "LaunchConnection", "cursor": cursor, "hasMore": hasMore])
   }
   public var __typename: String {
    get {
     return resultMap["__typename"]! as! String
    }
    set {
     resultMap.updateValue(newValue, forKey: "__typename")
    }
   }
   public var cursor: String {
    get {
     return resultMap["cursor"]! as! String
    }
    set {
     resultMap.updateValue(newValue, forKey: "cursor")
    }
   }
   public var hasMore: Bool {
    get {
     return resultMap["hasMore"]! as! Bool
    }
    set {
     resultMap.updateValue(newValue, forKey: "hasMore")
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: `print(error)`. Print **always** only `error` in a Decoding `catch` block. It tells you exactly what's wrong and where. At least I can see a typo. And delete `(let error)`. The `error` instance is available implicitly in a catch block.

Comment: There is no error. In the above code print(decode)  it prints LaunchesModel with value nil. Which means try JSONDecoder().decode(LaunchesModal.self, from: data) is not corking

Comment: It prints no error because you declared everything as optional. That’s not helpful while developing things.

Comment: thank you. now **it prints the data could not be read because it is missing.**.

Comment: Please reread my first comment!